# Вывод информации на экран

Tags: javascript, консоль

Здравствуйте. Пока я сидел и писал html/css код, у меня возникла одна замечательная идея. Но, к сожалению, я не знаю как реализовать ее, поэтому прошу помощи.

Мне нужно читать информацию, написанную, допустим, в `input type="text"` и выводить ее на экран, к примеру, в тот же `textarea`. Все бы ничего, если бы мои мысли не зашли так глубоко, что мне придется учить тот язык, который поможет мне в реализации данной идеи..

Но, при всем этом мне нужен не банальный вывод текста, а так, если пользователь ввел рандомный набор букв, то выходила информация:

```
"еррор, такой команды не существует"
```

а если пользователь ввел правильную команду,то соответственно, выводилась информация, что за команду ввел пользователь.

```
EXAMPLE:

блаблабла = syntax error;
random_money = Выдает рандомное количество денег, от 100-10000.
```

Естественно вы видели такие реализации. Яркий пример тому - codeacademy. 
В принципе это и есть то, что я хочу. Но расписать все же стоило.

У меня с другими языками глухо, и, желательно бы, чтобы вы посоветовали книжки, которые помогут мне в изучении описанного мною языка. Ах как же неохота учить еще один язык, но ради сей реализации я постараюсь..

Comment: я не понял, "описанный вами язык" это javascript или что ?

вот что-то такое... не codeacademy конечно :) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/49b8t/

Comment: eicto, В том-то и дело, что я даже не знаю НА чем все это нужно писать, поэтому и спрашиваю как и на каком языке это все можно реализовать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, вам нужен только Javascript.
Пользоваться им очень просто, т.к. не надобно ничего устанавливать. Только изучать и писать.

Собственно, javascript-файл должен называться Main.js. Онлайн он почему-то не работает.
http://jsfiddle.net/Xxcapog/zA6X5/

Comment: Так-то можно обучиться и по учебникам в интернете. Но если вы не хотите ограничиваться только простыми операциями, то надо браться за серьезную литературу, так как язык довольно сложный.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь-то мне действительно нужно будет вникать в этот javascript. Вы меня буквально спасли.

Я так подозреваю, если команд будет не 2 как в примере, а 100 и более, то для них всех надо тоже писать отдельный кусок куда? Правда это уже не так страшно выглядит :)

P.S Весь вчерашний день и до этого момента просидел в гугле в поиске ответа на мой вопрос, параллельно сидя в brackets и пробуя бессмысленные попытки что либо предпринять. Очень сильно хочется спать, но перед этим я все таки заставил себя зайти на сайт и посмотреть, есть ли еще ответы. Благо он нашелся =)

Comment: PPS: Да, ваш код не работает на http://jsfiddle.net/Xxcapog/zA6X5/ ,но благо он заработал на http://liveweave.com/rGKLfr . Я его немного модернизировал под мой вариант, поэтому прошу написать, если я где-то допустил ошибку. Конечно, я зайду проверить ваш ответ , но только когда буду в полной боеготовности.

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень понятно, чего вы хотите сделать с помощью этой программы) функция GiveMoney нигде не запускается)

И еще. Я не очень люблю использовать switch, так как всё время забываю, как это, собственно, записывается. Но вам эта штука сильно укоротит код)

Comment: Да, будучи в глубокой сонливости я удалил лишнего. Спасибо за подсказку. А про switch я почитаю, спасибо. Вообще спасибо за такой ответ. Честно, не ожидал что мне дадут ответ на мой 'ламерский' с точки зрения javascript-программиста вопрос :)